# getting module 'abc' has no attribute 'update_abstractmethods' error when installing/uninstalling a package

Tags: python, installation, pip, package, abc

starting from a few days ago every time I try downloading any packages to my environment (or pip installing directly through the terminal) and/or delete/uninstall an existing package in my envirinemt, I'm getting a package install/uninstall failure error:
File "C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\attr_make.py", line 740, in build_class
return self.abc.update_abstractmethods(
AttributeError: module 'abc' has no attribute 'update_abstractmethods'.

I made sure that abc library is importable (no issues). 2. on the _make.py file I traced the build class function, and it looks like that:

```
if PY310:
import abc
def build_class(self):
"""
Finalize class based on the accumulated configuration.
Builder cannot be used after calling this method.
"""
if self._slots is True:
return self._create_slots_class()
return self.abc.update_abstractmethods(
self._patch_original_class()
)
```

it's important to mention that all existing scripts and libraries up until the problem started is working fine, just can't seem to be able to make the pycharm downloading any packages (which just started randomly a few days ago, maybe after I tried to pip install a certain library)

Comment: Strange. `update_abstractmethods()` is part of the `abc` module as provided by Python. It is even documented here: https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/abc.html#abc.update_abstractmethods ... are you sure you're using Python's provided `abc` module and not import anything that overwrites that module?

Answer (score 0):

`abc.update_abstractmethods()` [was added in Python 3.10](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/abc.html#abc.update_abstractmethods). You're running Python 3.9 (guessed from the path "C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\ **Python39** \lib\site-packages\attr_make.py") so the method is not available.

Comment: the catch here, `where python` will retrieve the python39 folder location as you've seen: C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe, while ` python --version` retrieves Python 3.10.0. So seems like the interpreter is a 3.10 but the folders are under 3.9 (maybe it's a remaining legacy from an earlier version I've had). what would be the best shout here, maybe un-install and re-install 3.10? (anither interesting observation is when I'm tapping to the uninstall window on the control panel, the python software updated there is indeed the Python 3.9.0 (64-bit)

Comment: Uninstall 3.9 (if it's installed) and 3.10. Remove directory `C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39` . Install Python 3.10.